# DateTime and DateTimeOffset Conversion Issues

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

My ModelState is always being set to invalid because the CreatedAt value in one of my models is always coming back as Dates/############/ which results in a null value.  I am wondering why this is happening.  CreatedAt is DateTimeOffset.  I am fairly certain that it should be pulling a DateTimeOffset value from another Database table.

I have tried casting it to datetime, creating a new DateTimeOffset and passing that in, and just passing DateTimeOffset.Now to just get it to be valid.  None have worked.

```
public ActionResult EditSafetyIncidentPopUp([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, SafetyIncidentViewModel sivm)
{
    if (sivm != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SafetyIncident si = new SafetyIncident
        {
            Id = sivm.Id,
            CreatedAt = new DateTimeOffset(sivm.CreatedAt),
            Description = sivm.Description,
            Type = sivm.Type,
            ProductionLineId = sivm.ProductionLineId,
            ProdLine = _productionLineService.Find(sivm.ProductionLineId)
        };

        _safetyIncidentService.Update(si);
    }

    return this.Json(new[] { sivm }.ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));}


public class SafetyIncidentViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 1, ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid type.")]
    public type Type { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Production Line")]
    [Required]
    public string ProductionLineId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Production Line")]
    public ProductionLine ProdLine { get; set; }
}
```

I want the result to successfully update my database.  It currently only updates the grid and then fails to pass the data to the database because the ModelState is invalid.

Comment: Can you add your view model for sivm.

Comment: When you debug and inspect the model state, what property is throwing the model state error?

Comment: Added the ViewModel.

Comment: ProdLine.CreateAt is what sets ModelState to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view model to use a date time offset instead of a DateTime. Then there is no need for a conversion.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to convert between them?  I'm going to switch them all to DateTimeOffset but I've looked at other posts about how to convert between them and it did not solve the issue.